# How to upload a large files through ftp?

Tags: php, ftp

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY); 
// Upload the File
```

I cant upload the large files.Any help it would be great

Comment: define "Large" are we talking 1MB? 1GB? 1TB? 1PB?

Comment: What is the error you have received?

Comment: This code only works for 2MB files.I need solution for more than 1000MB

Comment: @ajreal I didn't  receive any errors.It perfectly works for below 2 MB files.when i try to upload more than it doesn't show any error message.

Comment: Warning: POST Content-Length of 10263832 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0.. Im getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
```

In your php.ini file

Increase these values as per your need.